# As a General Rule, who is authorized to taxi aircraft

Tags: aircraft-identification

Need Help with this question it is giving me a hard time

Comment: What country/jurisdiction? Also where? there may be different regulations for taxiing on taxiways and runways vs maneuvering around a ramp.

Comment: As a General Answer, I would say "a pilot". It's hard to be much more specific than that for such a general question.

Comment: It's an interesting question, e.g. when the aircraft has to go through maintenance.

Comment: Is this a study question for an exam? If so, knowing for what jurisdiction you are asking and for what aircraft type will help immensely. The rules for who may taxi a 747 in Brazil may be different from who may taxi a Grand Caravan in Vietnam. In most real-world cases, the person taxiing the plane is a pilot of the aircraft in question.

Answer (score 4):

Anyone can taxi an aircraft, if you know how.

The only limitations would be those stipulated by the aircraft owner and/or insurance company who would want to set some minimum experience or training so that nothing gets damaged.

Some airports have their own regulations as to who is qualified to taxi an aircraft. These airport regulations might vary depending on the complexity and size of the aircraft.

[PALM SPRINGS INTERNATIONAL AIRPORT
 Chapter 16.32 AIRCRAFT RULES AND REGULATIONS](http://www.qcode.us/codes/palmsprings/view.php?topic=16-16_32-16_32_055)

> *Only qualified persons shall start and/or operate an Aircraft engine at the Airport and/or taxi an Aircraft on the Airport. Qualified persons include a pilot, an airframe and power plant mechanic, or a qualified technician licensed by the FAA and qualified to start or operate the engine(s) and/or taxi that particular type and class of Aircraft*.

Depending on the jurisdiction,  a radio licence might also be required if you need to use the radio.

Comment: "A radio licence would also be required if you need to use the radio." - Not in the United States. In the US, no license is required to transmit using an airband radio while you're aboard an aircraft.

Answer (score 1):

Airports frequently have rules who could taxi the aircraft within they boundaries (normally pilot, student pilot or mechanic). [This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/14660/can-you-be-paid-to-taxi-an-aircraft-if-you-dont-have-a-commercial-license) contains more information.

Moving over ground between two points without intention of flying is not a flight.